# Periodic tasks with Delayed Job gem

Tags: ruby, delayed-job

```
class A < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.a
    A.first.touch
    delay(run_at: Proc.new{ 10.seconds.from_now }).a
    log.info 'Added job to run at ' + 10.seconds.from_now.to_s
  end

  def self.log
    @log ||= Logger.new 'dj.log'
  end
end
```

Why do I see this in worker log:

```
Added job to run at 2013-04-26 01:04:53 UTC
Added job to run at 2013-04-26 01:04:53 UTC
Added job to run at 2013-04-26 01:04:54 UTC
Added job to run at 2013-04-26 01:04:54 UTC
Added job to run at 2013-04-26 01:04:55 UTC
```

NOTE: Not separated 10 seconds.

Comment: So `A.a` enqueues a delayed job which calls `A.a`?

Comment: yes, `a` does some thing and enqueues to do same thing after 10 seconds

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If what you want is to run recurring tasks, for example, each day. You can use [rufus-scheduler](https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler):

```
rufus-scheduler is a Ruby gem for scheduling pieces of code (jobs)
```

Also there are some extensions for [resque](https://github.com/bvandenbos/resque-scheduler) and [sidekiq](https://github.com/yabawock/sidekiq-scheduler).

Hope it helps!

Comment: rufus-scheduler worked for me, could not make it work with whenever for PATH issues

Comment: Beware, `rufus` does not persist the tasks as `delayed_job` or `resque` do.

Comment: If you are using delayed_job, then there is this gem [delayed_job_recurring](https://github.com/amitree/delayed_job_recurring) available for scheduling recurring jobs. I have used it in multiple ROR-based applications and works smoothly.